# Google Analytics 4 API - Missing dateHourMinutes

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

It looks like Google Analytics 4 API doesn't offer reporting to the minutes.  The closest I can see in the Query Explorer is Date + Hour.

Is there a way to obtain data accurate to the minutes with GA4 reporting API?

Comment: Hi May I know will your dateHour working?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround could be to capture the hit timestamp as a custom dimension. Here's an example: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/#4-hit-timestamp

Note that link I shared sets up a custom dimension for Universal Analytics, not GA4. So for GA4 you would need to capture it as an event parameter and then create the custom dimension in the GA4 interface.

Alternatively, you could enable the export to BigQuery and the following field is provided in the schema: event_timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics 4 Data API added three new dimensions today: `dateHourMinute`, `minute`, and `nthMinute`. This [page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions) lists all dimensions and metrics available in the API.

These dimensions are compatible with some but not all other dimensions and metrics. For example, `minute` is compatible with `eventCount` and `activeUsers`, but `minute` is not compatible with `newUsers`. We're adding a new API method to show which dimensions and metrics are compatible with other dimensions and metrics.

Thanks,
Brett

The Google Analytics Team

Comment: Hi Brett - is this API method available yet? We've implemented `dateHourMinute` but getting compatibility errors back for some metrics & dimensions and we want to be sure which ones aren't meant to work with `dateHourMinute`. thank you for your help and for being active on this forum!

Comment: Yes, `dateHourMinute` is available. To see which dimensions & metrics are compatible with `dateHourMinute`, visit this page: https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/. Select your GA4 property. Check the `dateHourMinute` dimension. The grayed-out dimensions & metrics are not compatible with `dateHourMinute`.

Comment: Amazing, thanks Brett. That tells us what we need 

Comment: I want to calculate exitRate, dropFromPage, PageTime and pageImpression using GA4 API Beta version mentioned below https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1 But not able to find any metric for the same in documentation. Any Idea

Comment: Hey @Brett, we noticed that we're getting invalid results when sending out a query for `totalUsers`, indicating a `dateHour` dimension filter. We always seem to get 0 as response. Are there any plans to implement this specific dimension for the metrics that don't work with it? We checked the dimensions metric explorer linked above and these dimensions is not greyed out for the metric I mention.

Comment: Hey @ThisIsErico, does the 0 response contain `"subjectToThresholding": true`? If you've activated Google Signals, data thresholds may be applied if the `totalUsers` metric is used. There's more information here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Brett! Sadly, these requests are not subject to thresholding. Here's a link to a problematic request for us: https://gist.github.com/thisiserico/efbed0126065b11468f8c4bbc3b715b9

The moment we take the `dimensionFilter` out, we start getting results. However, that filter is most likely correct, as changing the metric from `totalUsers` to `sessions`, for example, also gets us valid results.

Maybe this is an issue we can scope to some specific metrics?

Comment: Looking at the explorer, I have selected dateHourMinute, but there are no "grayed-out" dimensions or metrics. but when I select my metric (totalUsers) and the custom dimensions I have, and make a request, I get that dateHourMinute is incompatible. Why dateHour is just fine, but dateHourMinute is not is pretty baffling. I guess I'll create another custom dimension

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a workaround but GA have said in April that they plan to add dateHourMinutes to GA4 API.